# Marshaling special characters in jaxb

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, jaxb, marshalling

I have a list of strings already stored in my program. I want to be able to marshall them into a xml file. I'm currently using JAXB for that, and when using the following code, I get all the accents as rare characters (as when you dont set the encodign to utf-8)

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Proyecto.class);      
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);  
m.marshal(p, System.out);
```

Problem is that my output xml is set to utf-8 already, so cannot see how can I avoid this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    .....
        <name_identity>ModificaciÃ³n...
    .....
```

The "correct" output should be "Modificación".
Any tips?

Comment: The problem is that the device _System.out_ is writing to is not decoding the bytes as UTF-8 but as some other encoding. If you wrote the data to file it would be correct.

Comment: Yes, it was that, tried to export to xml file and everything working. Thanks